# How to remove UI access to Custom Post Type using direct links?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-editor, user-interface

My goal: A custom post type with a complete custom editor page and post list table.

I have set `show_ui` to **false**. It removed the UI section. But if some admin puts direct link (wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=custom_post) in the browser, it takes them to the post table page, and clicking from there takes to editor page. How can I stop this? I don't want anyone to get access to this two pages. I have made two custom pages for them.

Or is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)! When [registering a post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), take a look at the `capability_type` and `capabilities`.

You can define a custom capability map for the standard `edit_post`, `delete_post`, etc. for your post type.

The thing you remember is, if you customize the capabilities, **YOU DON'T HAVE THESE CAPABILITIES EITHER!** This means you'll have to get those capabilities on your user role. (probably Administrator?)

You need to then either [create a new user role](https://managewp.com/create-custom-user-roles-wordpress) and assign capabilities to it, or just use a plugin like [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) which gives you a good interface to create these and assign capabilities to existing roles, as well as creating new roles altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the head Eric. If I set custom capability type, then it meets my goal somehow, as it won't allow anyone without the "new capability" permission to access those pages, not even administrator. And I actually don't need to provide that permission to anyone.
But there comes a new question: from the custom editor page, will be an admin without "new capability" permission able to submit posts? I will be using `wp_insert_post`.

Comment: I'd have to say.. test it? In `wp_insert_post` there is a capability check for setting the status to publish, but I don't see any others in the source code.

Comment: Thanks again. It will be quiet tough to test it at this moment, as the plugin is in the planning phase. However, I will write a simple code block to test this particular problem. Will update by tomorrow.